# Loop through a list using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I am attempting to write a batch file to automate the process of rebooting some IP cameras i have on a server.

I have successfully got a batch file to reboot one camera, via ftp, but I'm having trouble understanding how to do it for every ip in the range.

I currently have:

```
open IP
user
pass
quote site reboot
quote site reboot
quit
echo
```

saved in a .txt file (ftp.txt) and I call this using a .bat file:

```
@echo off
set user = Username
set pass = Password
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

I want to have a list of the ip addresses used, then have the bat script perform the reboot one by one, and wait for 2 minutes before moving to the next one.

I think i'll need to place the list in the     .txt     file the use a for loop in the bat.

something like

```
set ip = iplist(??)  <-- Part causing confusion
for each ip in ftp.txt
  open ip
  user
  pass
  quote site reboot
  quote site reboot
  pause 2 min
quit
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have different settings for the cameras (e.g. user), or just the _IP_ differs?

Comment: Only the IP addresses

Comment: "some IP cameras". Is that 3 or 300? Will the IP's be embedded in your bat file or in a text file?

Comment: I want information on how to do it. I imagine i'll have my list in a txt file, then the bat file uses that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it.
Modify your script (*script00.bat*):

```bat
@echo off

for /F %%f in (cameras.txt) do (
    ftp -s:ftp.txt %%f
)
```

**Notes**:

1. I removed the 2 *env var*s (*user* / *pass*) setting since they were not used anyway
2. [[SS64]: FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is used to iterate through each line of the *cameras.txt* file
3. Note the extra argument for *FTP* (it's the *IP*)
4. Store all the camera *IP*s in a file called *cameras.txt* (**one** *IP* per line)
5. Because of the 3<sup>rd</sup> note, the *IP* is passed as an argument to *FTP*, so it's no longer required in the *ftp.txt* file, therefore you should delete the 1<sup>st</sup> line (`open IP`)

Posting the other files content.

*cameras.txt*:

```
mirrors.kernel.org
ftp.kr.freebsd.org
```

*ftp.txt*:

```
anonymous
pass
quote site reboot
quote site reboot
quit
echo
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045327836]> script00.bat
> Connected to mirrors.pdx.kernel.org.
> 220 Welcome to mirrors.kernel.org.
> 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
> User (mirrors.pdx.kernel.org:(none)):
> 331 Please specify the password.
>
> 230 Login successful.
> ftp> quote site reboot
> 550 Permission denied.
> ftp> quote site reboot
> 550 Permission denied.
> ftp> quit
> 221 Goodbye.
> Connected to daemon.kr.freebsd.org.
> 220 daemon.kr.freebsd.org FTP server (Version 6.00LS) ready.
> 500 OPTS UTF8 ON: command not understood.
> User (daemon.kr.freebsd.org:(none)):
> 331 Guest login ok, send your email address as password.
>
> 230 Guest login ok, access restrictions apply.
> ftp> quote site reboot
> 500 SITE REBOOT: command not understood.
> ftp> quote site reboot
> 500 SITE REBOOT: command not understood.
> ftp> quit
> 221 Goodbye.
> ```

which I think it's what you're after.

For more details on *FTP* command, check: [[MS.Learn]: ftp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp)